# Selenium with Python Chrome only able to load page when in compatibility mode then reverts out of compatibility mode after each use

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, python-3.9

Trying to run a browser to do some mindless clicking at work.  Unless in compatibility mode, chrome opens and spins Loading... with data:' in the address bar.  My personal machine works fine on the wifi.

If I put chrome in compatibility mode (Windows 8) through properties, page loads fine but after each time if I restart the code I find chrome is no longer in compatibility mode and same problem as before.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://google.com/')
time.sleep(5)
driver.close()
```

That is the code I am running.  chromedriver is in path and is the corresponding version for version 90 of chrome.

Work computer has both azure and onedrive.

Should note that I am fairly new to python/selenium.

Fixed https same problem

Comment: `driver.get('http://google.com')` Most probably you have a typo/ Remove / in the end

Comment: changed it and same problem